# Como é mantido financeiramente o Stack Exchange e o Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: debate, suporte

Sou aluno no curso de Mestrado Profissional em Educação Tecnológica do Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia do Triângulo Mineiro – IFTM – Campus Uberaba - Linha de Pesquisa: Tecnologias da Informação e Comunicação (TICs), Inovação Tecnológica e Mudanças Educacionais.

Um dos meus objetos de estudo será o Stack Overflow, pois pelo pouco que vi, acredito muito no potencial da rede Stack Exchange, como nova forma de construção de conhecimento. As perguntas e respostas aqui feitas, de forma participativa, estão criando um banco de dados de informações sem precedentes. E o mais importante são as interações e participação ativa dos usuários.

Gostaria de saber quando começou o Stack Overflow no Brasil e como ele, assim como o Stack Exchange, se mantem financeiramente? Vi que não existem propagandas no portal. Onde posso obter mais informações sobre o Stack Exchange e mais especificamente sobre o Stack Overflow?

Comment: A parte financeira está respondida aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358/quem-%C3%A9-o-stackexchange. E tem mais informações aqui: http://stackexchange.com/about.

Comment: Estou na dúvida se marco como dup. A outra não responde a parte histórica.

Comment: Só um adendo, apesar do foco principal da Stack Exchange com o Stack Overflow em Português ser o público brasileiro, é tecnicamente incorreto falar "Stack Overflow Brasil", pois existem vários usuários de outros países aqui, principalmente (mas não somente) de Portugal. Como você está fazendo um estudo sobre isso achei importante ressaltar. Já é um pouquinha de história ;-)

Comment: E aqui vão alguns links que podem lhe ajudar a colher informações sobre o site: [Area 51 - Stack Overflow (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese), [Olá, Mundo! Announcing Stack Overflow in Portuguese.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/) e [Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/)

Comment: Agradeço pela indicação do material. Concordo que foi um erro falar Stack Overflow no Brasil, o correto é  Stack Overflow no em Português.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta sou de Manaus e estou tentando mestrado pelo Instituto Federal do Amazonas- IFAM, cheguei a fazer um projeto próximo a sua linha de pesquisa e gostaria de entrar em contato com você para falar sobre o assunto. seria possível? pode ser pelo facebook.